# help my Bitcoin core wallet won't sync

Tags: wallet, synchronization

more  Bitcoin core won't synchronize with network but my wallet has a balance of 0.00  it I have done transactions that reply back as true and if I do balance for those addresses it shows transactions  current in the console then I look around main wallet and still 0

Comment: how is your internet connection? what is your OS?

Comment: What Bitcoin Core version? What does getchaintips in the console report?